# Background not appearing

Tags: html, css

I notice that [the background image here](http://tinyurl.com/8dz55kx) (on the "cont" element) 
doesn't appear as it does on [my home page here](http://tinyurl.com/8eczmsv).
I see it has something to do with the height, as when I add a height it works, except it also messes up the footer somehow...
How can I make the background work on the page just as it works on the home page?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried a clearfix? find which elements are 0 and add clearfix or whatever solution you prefer.

Comment: Since your background was set to the element `div.cont` and it haven't any clearfix, it is with 0 height. Add clearfix and it'll work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your `.cont` element. The issue is that since your elements inside it are `floated`, it won't resize to fit their height.

Generically, this can be fixed by many methods, not just `overflow: hidden;`. [Google for clearfix](http://google.com/search?q=clearfix) to find resources.

Comment: It works, except, it messes up my footer.  I am trying to figure out why.  Do you have any idea?  You can see for yourself by simply Inspecting the "cont" element and adding `overflow: hidden;` as you recommended.

Comment: Oh, wait, it looks like this is caused by another element being named "cont" within the "footer" element.  I will amend that and it should work.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user1477388 It's because you have another `div` with class `.cont` inside it. Try changing it to another class, or override it using `.footer .cont { overflow: visible; }`

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I fixed this issue before by adding the overflow, but I couldn't think of it in this situation.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Use clearfix:

Append `<div style="clear: both"></div>` to the end of `#cont` div.

In production websites I'm using:

```
<br class="clear"/>
```

Plus css:

```
br.clear { display: block; width: 1px; height: 0px; clear: both; }
```

Comment: Thanks but the clearfix didn't seem to help in this scenario.

Comment: Oh, thanks.  I didn't realize.  I will still go with the CSS method since it uses less code.  But, good job.

Comment: @rogal: you don't need to specify a unit if value is zero (0)

Answer (score 1):

Since your `background-image` was set to the element `div.cont` and it haven't any clearfix, it is with **0 height** so your background have no space to appear. *Add a clearfix and it'll work*. One way to do it is:

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="body">
  ...
  </div>

  <br style="clear: both" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the clearfix didn't seem to help in this scenario.

Comment: I changed your code on the fly with the `Google Chrome Inspector` and it worked fine. Take a closer look to see if you are putting the clearfix in the right place.